# How to verify that a repository is called n times inside a method which is being tested with junit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, repository

I can't find any way to verify that `impegnoAmmessoRepo.save(item_old)` is called N times during the execution of the following method:

```
public void deleteOldImpegniAmmessi(List<ProgettoImpegnoAmmesso> newList, Integer idPagamento ) {

    List <ProgettoImpegnoAmmesso> all_items = impegnoAmmessoRepo.findAllByIdImpegnoIdImpegno(idPagamento);

    for (ProgettoImpegnoAmmesso item_old : all_items ) {
        if(! newList.contains(item_old)) {
            item_old.setFlagValido(ValidFlagType._NOT_VALID.validity());
            item_old.setDataFine(new Date());
            impegnoAmmessoRepo.save(item_old);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I have to use the annotation `@Mock` on the repository and to use the method `verify()`, but I don't know how to use it for a method (the `save()` of the repository) which is invoked inside another method that is being invoked (`deleteOldImpegniAmmessi`).

Comment: Mockito has methods to do that, you can also write your own mock class to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via verify function as :

```
Mockito.verify(impegnoAmmessoRepo,Mockito.times(N)).save(any(ProgettoImpegnoAmmesso .class));
```

`times` function will help you do this